# SpringBoot 3 extend PostgresSQL Dialect

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We have the custom postgres dialect, by extending Postgres Dialect, and registerFunctions, but looks like this is not supported in spring boot 3.

What are the alternative ways to implement this in spring boot 3.

```
public class GlobalPostgresDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {

    public static final String STRING_AGG = "string_agg";
    public static final String STRING_AGG_ORDER_BY = "string_agg_order_by";
    public static final String STRING_AGG_DISTINCT = "string_agg_distinct";
    public static final String STRING_AGG_DISTINCT_ORDER_BY = "string_agg_distinct_order_by";
    public static final String ARRAY_AGG = "array_agg";
    public static final String ARRAY_AGG_DISTINCT = "array_agg_distinct";
    public static final String ARRAY_AGG_ORDER_BY = "array_agg_order_by";
    public static final String ARRAY_AGG_DISTINCT_ORDER_BY = "array_agg_distinct_order_by";
    public static final String COUNT_DISTINCT_5_ARGS = "count_distinct_5_args";

    public GlobalPostgresDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction(STRING_AGG, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2)"));
        registerFunction(STRING_AGG_ORDER_BY, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2 order by ?3)"));
        registerFunction(STRING_AGG_DISTINCT, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(distinct ?1, ?2)"));
        registerFunction(STRING_AGG_DISTINCT_ORDER_BY, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(distinct ?1, ?2 order by ?3)"));
        registerFunction(ARRAY_AGG, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "array_agg(?1)"));
        registerFunction(ARRAY_AGG_DISTINCT, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "array_agg(distinct ?1)"));
        registerFunction(ARRAY_AGG_ORDER_BY, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "array_agg(?1 order by ?2)"));
        registerFunction(ARRAY_AGG_DISTINCT_ORDER_BY, new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "array_agg(?1, ?2 order by ?2)"));
        registerFunction(COUNT_DISTINCT_5_ARGS, new SQLFunctionTemplate(LongType.INSTANCE, "count(distinct(?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5))"));
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to find answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

@Override
public void initializeFunctionRegistry(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
    super.initializeFunctionRegistry(functionContributions);
    SqmFunctionRegistry functionRegistry = functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry();
    TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration = functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration();

    BasicTypeRegistry basicTypeRegistry = typeConfiguration.getBasicTypeRegistry();
    // Example
    functionRegistry.patternDescriptorBuilder( "radians", "(?1*acos(-1)/180)" )
            .setInvariantType(basicTypeRegistry.resolve(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN))
            .setExactArgumentCount(1)
            .setParameterTypes(NUMERIC)
            .register();
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).